# Does the time of download in the Tweepy library depend on the internet connection?

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm collecting tweets that belong to some specific ID accounts and it is taking more than 12 hours for every 200 IDs. Does it depend on the internet connection or my lines of code could be more efficient? Thanks in advance for the help!

```
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True) 

for id_ in ids:
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    
    outtweets = []
    
    try:
    
        for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,id=id_).items():

            outtweets.append({'id':id_,
                  'tw_id_str': tweet.id_str, 
                  'tw_created_at':tweet.created_at, 
                  'tw_favorite_count':tweet.favorite_count, 
                  'tw_retweet_count':tweet.retweet_count, 
                  'tw_text':tweet.text.encode("utf-8").decode("utf-8")})
        df = pd.DataFrame(outtweets)
        df.to_csv("tweets_of_ids.csv", mode='a')

    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        continue
```

ps: I can't remove wait_on_rate_limit otherwise it gives me error code 401 and I have to regenerate the access token.

Answer (score 0):

Using `wait_on_rate_limit` causes Tweepy to slow down to make sure your bot does not consume all available calls and then starts throwing errors.

The bandwidth between your bot and Twitter adds some latency but given the throughput you experience (and considering you only download text) it is not the bottleneck.